# Conditional in a method that way more than often has already been satisified

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Although this question is not specific to Java an explanation that targeted Java specifically would be helpful. My problem is I have done several programs and I have also manipulated pre-existing games and I find that there are often checks for something that 99% or more of the time doesn't really have to do with what the person is trying to do.

Lets say I have an achievement system and you have to do something to earn an achievement like do a dance. People dance all the time and they have earned this achievement long ago and have just been dancing for hours on end. Each time they dance there is going to be a check to see if they have done the achievement so that if they haven't they can be given the achievement. **How can I get around checking something once it does not apply to a person anymore?**

Comment: Can you be more specific? Like post a code snippet, show what you mean, where you are looking for something else.

Comment: `public method dance() { if(!personHasAchievement(Achievement.DANCE) { givePersonAchievement(Achievement.DANCE); } doAction(Action.DANCE);}` The person gets their achievement the first time they dance and then everytime after they're just trying to dance but they have to go through this check the next 50 million dances anyway. @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: I forgot to ask, but what is your goal? Cleaner code? Performance improvement?

Comment: Performance improvement is probably number one. Simply the learning aspect might be above that though. I understand that Java is very quick with _most_ conditional checks and it often makes little to no difference but, as I see it, better is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like an Event Bus. Your `dance` method will create an event which will be pushed into the Event Bus. Initially, there will be part of the code which is going to listen to the dance event. Once the listener is triggered by the dance event, it will unregister itself as a listener of dance event.

EDIT:
Similar idea without using EventBus.

```
interface DanceEventHandler {
    void handle(DanceEvent e);
}
```

Let say there is a `User` object for each user.

```
class User {
    ....
    DanceEventHandler danceEventHandler;
}
```

Initially you can use an implementation which does something about a dance event.

```
class DefaultDanceEventHandler {
    void handle(DanceEvent e) {
        //Give achievement to the user
    }
}
```

Once the user already have the achievement, replace the `danceEventHandler` in user with a different implementation.

```
class AfterAchievementDanceEventHandler {
    void handle(DanceEvent e) {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this still be applicable if it were applied to a situation where many people are using one-time-conditional methods on the same server?

Comment: In that case you might want to have a different event for different user. A bit unrelated to the original question, if it a separate server, I would argue to set the whole achievement system as a separate service which can still use an Event Bus, completely separate it from the main service.